# I need get string from string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need get string from string, this is be js code. For example i have a string

```
"Bla bla bla, i am a minuon 
[script]document.getELementById; var a = "a";[script]";
```

I will need function which return `"document.getELementById; var a = "a";"`.
Thanks.

Comment: update your question. Couldnt able to understand what is the problem?

Comment: So what have you tried? We wont just code for you.

Comment: have you tried anything? have you thought about replace?

Comment: If you have to return all text between [script] tags, you can use regex to find it

Comment: please post a fiddle if possible. or at least clarify your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have only one instance of the `[script]` tags, you can just do this:

```
var string = "Bla bla bla, i am a minuon [script]document.getELementById; var a = \"a\";[script] more"; 

var result = string.split("[script]")[1];
```

`[0]` would be everything before the first script tag, and `[2]` would be everything after the second.

Answer (score 1):

try match method

```
str.match(/\[script\](.*?)\[script\]/)[1]
```